# Assign taxonomy term to a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I would like to set a taxonomy for a view. I have Taxonomy called "CMS Templates" and under that I have "Drupal". I would like to set Drupal for a view which is displaying Drupal templates but I don't know how. I tried to put field taxonomy and all taxonomies but I don't have possibility to set it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily output taxonomy term based information by going to admin/structure/views/add and under "Show" choose "Taxonomy terms".

Comment: Sorry I just don't get it. How can it help me?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. Are you trying to filter content by the taxonomy term "Drupal"?

Comment: I am trying to display breadcrumbs which belongs to some taxonomy. To do it I need to put a view in this taxonomy but I don't know how.